# In extjs 6 how to achieve the multiple instances of store assign to the same grid

Tags: extjs, extjs5, extjs6

In extjs 6 how to achieve the multiple instances of store assign to the same grid.

I created a grid and bind the store by creating stores in the viewmodel of that view and did the binding through the "bind"

Now i want to open same grid in multiple tabs..so that user can see diff data in two diff tabs..as i am using same grid and same store how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. Put a different grid instance in the different tabs, each with their own store.

I suppose if you *really* had to, you could use the tabchange event to swap the store out when the tab changes, but that's messy.

Why do you insist on having just the one grid instance? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score -1):

Well, normally, you `define` the grid once:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Grid.ContentGrid',{
    extend:'Ext.grid.Panel',
    xtype:'ContentGrid',
    initComponent:function() {
        var me = this;
        Ext.apply(me,{
            columns:[{
                ...
            }],
            listeners:{
                cellcontextmenu: function() {
                }
            }
        });
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

and then, in the view, you can use it as often as you wish through either Component hierarchy definition (more or less static) or Ext.create (at runtime):

```
Ext.define('Ext.Window',{
    layout:'card',
    items:[{
        xtype:'ContentGrid',
        store:'ABCStore',
    },{
        xtype:'ContentGrid',
        store:'DEFStore',
    }],
    listeners:{
        boxready:function(window) {
            window.add(
                Ext.create('MyApp.view.Grid.ContentGrid',{
                    store:'GHIStore'
                })
            );
        }
    }
});
```